# how to remove space between and right side of page

Tags: html, css, whitespace

How can i remove this space between body and right side of page?

See full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/4tqdejyx/

```
<div class="social">
    <h4 class="social-text">#Social</h4>
    <ul class="lista">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="Contact-us">
    <div class="contact-button "> <p class="dugme"><button class="cbtn">Contact us</button></p></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <img src="" class="logo" alt="logo"/>
    <h4 class="bk-text2">Buddy/Kitty</h4>
    <p>&copy;All rights reserved!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: We can't tell you from a screenshot. Please add your code to your post and create a verifiable demo of the problem - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `body { margin: 0; }`? Just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Set the container's or body's width property to `100%` to cover the complete width of the browser window. I could be more specific if you shower your code or made a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The `left` class has a `left-margin` of `2%`

The `right` class has a `right-margin` of `8%`

I think that's where the problem lies and not with the body. Change your CSS for `right` to the following and it should fix the problem you're seeing.

```
.right {
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-left: auto;
  float: right;
}
```

---

Also...

It looked like you were having some problems with lining up your `<div class="social">` correctly, so I made some changes to those tags. I also aligned your login button to hug to the right side to be symmetrical with the play button on the left.

https://jsfiddle.net/dotspencer/4tqdejyx/5/

Comment: Thank you,but when i  spread my browser window i further have  white space on right side

Comment: Does it show white space on this page? https://fiddle.jshell.net/dotspencer/4tqdejyx/5/show/